# .BAT break out of multiple nested loop, after finishing the respective list

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, nested-loops, breakout

I know breaking out of a nested loop is fairly easy, however, I'm not sure how to do it when I'm working with multiple lists of servers. Here's the scenario:

Goal: Search for sessions on a server matching a specific user ID, and also kill any disconnected sessions found

Problem: I have multiple lists of farms. I want to cycle through the lists until I find the users session, and then stop when that list is finished (not stop when the session is cleared, they may have multiple sessions in the farm).

Farmlist1.txt
farmlist2.txt
farmlist3.txt

If the session is found in farmlist2.txt, I want to FINISH searching in that list, but don't continue to farmlist3.txt.

Here's what I have so far, and it works like a charm. (Optimizations welcomed)

```
@echo off
echoCitrix Session Reset
echo.
echo This will look for a specific userID AND kill disconnected sessions on     all servers!
set /p userid=User ID of the user: 
for %%a in (q:\scripts\1common\citrixlists\*.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (%%a) do (
ping %%l -n 1 | find /i "TTL=" > nul 
if errorlevel 1 (
echo server %%l down or out of Load
) else (
echo Looking for %username% and killing disconnected sessions on %%l

for /f "tokens=3" %%b in ('qwinsta *tcp /server:%%l ^| find /i "%userid%"') do echo %%b | rwinsta %%b /server:%%l && echo SESSION FOR %userid% KILLED ON %%l

for /f "tokens=2" %%i IN ('qwinsta /server:%%l ^| find /i "disc"') DO (
if %%i gtr 0 (
rwinsta %%i /server:%%l && echo Disconnected sessions terminated
)

)

)

)

)
```

Comment: What is the _fairly easy_ way you are talking about?

Comment: And why are you left-justifying all your parenthetical code blocks?  That makes your code harder to read and harder to maintain.  To break out of the list, just `set "found=1"`; then at the end of your loop, `if defined found goto :EOF`.  If you're asking how you can make working code better, your question might be more appropriate on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batch).

Answer (score 0):

I do not exactly understand what you are trying to accomplish, but I do understand how to break out of nested `for` loops (or any other nested parenthesised blocks of code). So let me elaborate on that.

Breaking a single `for` loop is simple: put `goto :STOP` into the loop and the label `:STOP` in the line following the loop structure. The example below breaks the loop depending on its loop counter value:

```
@echo off
for /L %%I in (0,1,5) do (
    if %%I GTR 3 (
        echo Break!
        goto :STOP
    )
    echo %%I
)
:STOP
```

Although the loop is specified to count up to `5`, the output is:

```
0
1
2
3
Break!
```

Note that the loop actually completes the counting internally, but no more commands are executed. You can easily reproduce that when you increase the end value `5` to a huge number like `1000000`.

---

But now let us concentrate on nested loops (two in each example):

1. The following code snippet breaks both loops upon a certain condition is met:

   ```
   @echo off
   for %%J in (Aa Bb Cc) do (
       for /L %%I in (0,1,5) do (
           if "%%~J"=="Bb" if %%I GTR 3 (
               echo Break!
               goto :STOP
           )
           echo %%J-%%I
       )
   )
   :STOP
   ```

   The output is:

   ```
   Aa-0
   Aa-1
   Aa-2
   Aa-3
   Aa-4
   Aa-5
   Bb-0
   Bb-1
   Bb-2
   Bb-3
   Break!
   ```

   As you can see, execution of the loop construct is interrupted immediately at a certain point.
2. The batch file here breaks the outer loop when the a certain condition in the inner loop is met. The result of the check is transferred to the outer loop using a variable `FLAG`:

   ```
   @echo off
   set "FLAG="
   for %%J in (Aa Bb Cc) do (
       for /L %%I in (0,1,5) do (
           if "%%~J"=="Bb" if %%I GTR 3 (
               echo Break!
               set "FLAG=#"
           )
           echo %%~J-%%I
       )
       if defined FLAG goto :STOP
   )
   :STOP
   ```

   The output is:

   ```
   Aa-0
   Aa-1
   Aa-2
   Aa-3
   Aa-4
   Aa-5
   Bb-0
   Bb-1
   Bb-2
   Bb-3
   Break!
   Bb-4
   Break!
   Bb-5
   ```

   You will notice that the inner loop finishes execution before the outer one is broken.
3. The script below breaks the inner loop when a certain condition is net. To not break the outer loop, a sub-routine holding the inner loop and being called (`call`) from the outer one is required to hide the code block context of the outer loop from the `goto` break-up method:

   ```
   @echo off
   for %%J in (Aa Bb Cc) do (
       call :SUB "%%~J"
   )
   goto :EOF

   :SUB
   for /L %%I in (0,1,5) do (
       if "%~1"=="Bb" if %%I GTR 3 (
           echo Break!
           goto :STOP
       )
       echo %~1-%%I
   )
   :STOP
   ```

   The output is:

   ```
   Aa-0
   Aa-1
   Aa-2
   Aa-3
   Aa-4
   Aa-5
   Bb-0
   Bb-1
   Bb-2
   Bb-3
   Break!
   Cc-0
   Cc-1
   Cc-2
   Cc-3
   Cc-4
   Cc-5
   ```

   Here the outer loop finishes its execution without being affected by the broken inner one.

---

I hope one of the (last two) examples suits the requirements for your script.