# Breaking a batch FOR loop with a changing set

Tags: batch-file, cmd

[This](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=17351#p17351) solution suggests to break an inner FOR loop enclosed inside an outer FOR loop by using BREAK variable and keeping the entire loop code inside "*if not defined break*" parenthesis. It doesn't work though in the case below, where the "set" inside parentheses changes with each outer loop iteration aiming to minimize total runtime, and ECHO is used to verify that the inner loop may still run through a potentially long vars list even if its code inside IF condition is not executed. Without ECHO its hard to verify.

The question is: is there a way to break the inner loop in case when its "set" is changing?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "vars=1 2 3 4 5 6" & set "cars= a b c d e f"

for %%p in (%vars%) do (set "break=" & echo/
    for %%k in (!cars!) do (echo '!break!'
        if not defined break (set "%%k=%%p" & echo %%k=%%p
            set "cars=!cars: %%k=!" & echo '!cars!' & set break=TRUE)))

exit /b

:: Output
''
a=1
' b c d e f'
'TRUE'
'TRUE'
'TRUE'
'TRUE'
'TRUE'

''
b=2
' c d e f'
'TRUE'
'TRUE'
'TRUE'
'TRUE'

''
c=3
' d e f'
'TRUE'
'TRUE'
'TRUE'

''
d=4
' e f'
'TRUE'
'TRUE'

''
e=5
' f'
'TRUE'

''
f=6
''
```

Comment: Related: [.BAT break out of multiple nested loop, after finishing the respective list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040273/bat-break-out-of-multiple-nested-loop-after-finishing-the-respective-list/37041525#37041525)

Comment: Is there a typo: `uars` (set but never used) and `cars` (never preset)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This snippet demonstrates that a second FOR loop with a changing "set" breaks, if it's called from the first loop as an outside function.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "vars=1 2 3 4 5 6" & set "cars= a b c d e f"

for %%p in (%vars%) do (set "break=" & echo/
    call :loop)
exit /b

:loop
for %%k in (!cars!) do (echo '!break!'
    if not defined break (set "%%k=%%p" & echo %%k=%%p
        set "cars=!cars: %%k=!" & echo '!cars!' & set break=TRUE & exit /b))
exit /b

:: Output
''
a=1
' b c d e f'

''
b=2
' c d e f'

''
c=3
' d e f'

''
d=4
' e f'

''
e=5
' f'

''
f=6
''
```

Comment: This should not be posted as an answer as it is just some additional information for the question, so you should rather [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38368159/edit) the question... anyway, the answer is: **no**, there is no other method, there is no `exit for` command as in some languages; actually, even the sub-routine approach using `exit /B` or `goto :outside_of_loop` does actually not really break or leave the loop, because it finishes iterating in the background; but the context of the parenthesised block is broken; that is why you cannot use `goto :label` within a loop...

Comment: The above provides an answer for the case when 2nd loop "set" is changing during the 1st loop iteration. That was never addressed before, as per my search. However, GOTO :label doesn't break the 2nd loop in my testing without using a function regardless whether 2nd loop "set" changes or not. Instead it breaks both loops altogether.

Comment: @aschipfl The function method indeed breaks the 2nd loop. It does NOT finish the "set" iteration in the background, as shown above in my answer Output section, in contrast with non-function based method. :) GOTO :label method may work if placed outside the inner loop.

Comment: Tested again, still GOTO :label method breaks 2 loops, no way to break just one loop. You also confirmed that in your above note linked thread.

Comment: Try `@for /L %%I in (1,1,10000000) do @(echo Halt! & exit /B)` in a batch file; although `exit /B` is executed already during the first iteration, the script waits a well noticeable amount of time as the loop finishes iterating in the background; the `echo` demonstrates that the code in the loop body is executed once only; the same is true for `goto :somewhere`. The only way to really break a loop is `exit` without `/B` (but this breaks more obviously). Your `if not defined break` approach does also not break anything, it simply skips some code in case the condition is not fulfilled...

Comment: Yes, `goto` and `exit /B` break all parenthesised block if code they are nested in, including `for` loops and `if` conditions; there is no other way around but using sub-routines and `call`...

Comment: I can confirm you're correct in the above example. FOR /L loop keeps iterating despite EXIT /B used, but it doesn't prove that FOR loop (which is a different FOR method) also keeps iterating in the background if placed in a function and IF... EXIT /B is executed. My above answer output shows the opposite. :) I agree that using BREAK variable doesn't seem different from using any other variable inside IF clause, the loop continues unless function is used. However, its not my method, but linked in the question.

Comment: `@for /R "C:\" %%I in ("*.*") do @(echo Halt! & exit /B)` shows the same effect as `for /L`... :-)

Comment: Many questions on SO contain several relevant sub-questions linked by a common topic. Its typical for people answering questions to address only the detail they know about, and omit answering the details they don't. It goes like that in real life too. I found the answer to my own question, and feel it can be useful for other SO readers namely as the answer, not as a question. I appreciate your opinion, but everyone has the right to own opinion.

Comment: Edited question and answer as suggested to remove ambiguity.