# Unable to break out of For loop to another For loop

Tags: batch-file

Using a batch script, I am tying to break out of an inner for loop and land on the outer for loop to carry on the sequence but it returns an error saying:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect
```

It is referring to the my **:breakerpoint** label. Please advice. Thank you.

```
for /l %%A in (1, 1, %NumRuns%) do (
echo Doing run %%A of %NumRuns%

    for /l %%B in (1, 1, 3) do (
        ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > NUL
        tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Reel.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Reel.exe">NUL
        echo innerloop top
    echo Error lvl is %ERRORLEVEL%
    if NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
        echo innerloop middle
        goto:breakerpoint 
    )
    echo innerloop bottom
)
taskkill /F /IM "Reel.exe"
:breakerpoint rem this is error line

)
:end
echo end of run

pause
```

Comment: Related: [.BAT break out of multiple nested loop, after finishing the respective list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37041525)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `goto` breaks always the current code block and the current code block is the complete block beginning with the first parenthesis, in your case you leave all nested `FOR` at once.

To avoid this you need to use sub functions.

```
for /L %%A in (1, 1, %NumRuns%) do (
    echo Doing run %%A of %NumRuns%
    call :innerLoop
)
exit /b

:innerLoop
for /L %%B in (1, 1, 10) do (
  echo InnerLoop %%B from outerLoop %%A
  if %%B == 4 exit /b
)
exit /b
```