# How to end For /F loop after one cycle

Tags: batch-file

Trying to end the following loop after n number of loops. I am not sure how to begin. Any advice?

```
for /f "skip=11" %%i in ('sqlplus <dbuser>/<dbpass>@<dbname>@<spl_file_path and name>') do set VAR=%%i
```

i just want the first value that is brought back. There are 4 additional lines I would like to not include.

Comment: Also related: [.BAT break out of multiple nested loop, after finishing the respective list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37041525)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `GOTO` to exit the loop

```
for /f "skip=11" %%i in ('COMMAND') do (
  set VAR=%%i
  goto:next)

:next
echo %var%
```