# How to break the FOR Loop Inside the batch file?

Tags: asp.net, batch-file, cmd, command-line-arguments, batch-processing

Here is my code :

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NCR\APTRA\Aggregate 
Installer\Inventory\Aggregate\APTRA Self-Service Support" /f 06.04.01') do set "AppPath=%%~b"
echo %AppPath%

cmd /k
```

So when we run this batch file command prompt will open, so my requirement is when i click on Enter we need to break the FOR LOOP as the command prompt is not getting closed, Could any one please help me out ?

Comment: I know how to [break out of `for` loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37041525), but I do not understand your question. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: There may be no need to break out of the loop if your registry search pattern was more specific. _you appear to know the exact location of that data in advance_. Could you please show us the exact key, value and data content you are trying to parse.

Comment: When we run that batch file command prompt screen will come showing the message 1 Match Found ! And with the location C:pangaea\batchfile , so when i click enter button that should close But this is repeating C:pangaea\batchfile C:pangaea\batchfile C:pangaea\batchfile C:pangaea\batchfile C:pangaea\batchfile even though i press enter, I couldnt attach the screen shot to show you

Comment: With that code this is repeating with for loop C:pangaea\batchfile, C:pangaea\batchfile, C:pangaea\batchfile I wanted to close the cmd with enter button with that code in short to say !

Comment: I wanted to get out of that output after the command prompt opens with the enter key !

Answer (score 0):

try with goto:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NCR\APTRA\Aggregate 
Installer\Inventory\Aggregate\APTRA Self-Service Support" /f 06.04.01') do (
 set "AppPath=%%~b"
 goto :break
)
:break
echo %AppPath%

cmd /k
```

Comment: Yes, When i try to run this code command prompt not opening ! running and closing at the same time , But Command prompt needs to open that should show the message and when we click on enter than that needs to close

Answer (score 0):

Use the pause command, it will hold the console screen if there is no error.